# How to use Cursor to compare elements of it to eachother?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to use a cursor in PL/SQL.
I want to compare the elements of cursor to each other.
For example I have a JOB table and this tables contains job_number, I want to compare job_number with  each other to find whether there is same job_number in this table

```
declare
  jobisn    job.job_number%type;
  cursor c1 is
    select t.job_isn
      from job t; 
begin 
for i in c1 loop -- what should I code here ?
```

Comment: It would help if you could provide some sample data, along with what you want to be output and why. My first gut reaction is that you won't need to loop round a cursor; you'll be able to do it in a single select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acheive this with one sql statement -

```
select job_isn, count(*)
from job
group by job_isn
having count(*) > 1;
```

If you want to do it with a cursor anyway (even though its slower and not fit for your needs), just run this code inside the cursor -

```
select count(*)
into v_num_jobs
from job
where job_isn = i.job_isn;

if v_num_jobs > 1 then
    dbms_output.put_line(i.job_isn||' job has duplicates');
endif;
```

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use native sql to do that. you can know how many times that job number appeared on that table by doing this:

```
       select job_number, count(job_number) over(partition by job_number) from job;
```